# I have such a problem, does not see the library (import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;)

Tags: android

I have such a problem, does not see the library 
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have build error, try to rebuild and share build error

Comment: Are you using androidX?

Comment: Are you using androidX - Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Adapter class, you have imported the recyclerview module twice(first import is from android.support, and second import if from androidx(second last import line)). If you look in the import section, you are currently using Recyclerview from the Androidx support library. So you don't need the first import line. Remove the "import android.support.v7...Recyclerview" line.

if you want to include recyclerview from androidx then paste this code in gradle file and sync

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

**Please note** that if you enabled Androidx when creating the project OR you migrated to androidx(From android studio menu), you must only use Androidx support libraries. Similarly, if you are using appcompat(support.v7/v4.appcompat) libraries, then you should not use Androidx libraries. It is better to use Androidx libraries. Basically, you should not use libraries from both Androidx and appcompat in the same project. Every module/widget available in the appcompat is in the Androidx support libraries.